# The space character as a punctuator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In chapter 7.7 (Punctuators) of the ECMAScript spec ( http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf ) the grid of punctuators appears to have a gap in row 3 of the last column. This is in fact the space character punctuator, correct?

I understand that space characters may be inserted **optionally** between tokens in the JavaScript code (in order to improve readability), however, I was wondering where they are actually **required**...

In order to find this out, I searched for space characters in the minified version of the jQuery library. These are my results:

A space is <strike>required</strike>... (see Update below)

... between a keyword and an identifier:

```
function x(){}
var x;
return x;
typeof x;
new X();
```

... between two keywords:

```
return false;
if(x){}else if(y){}else{}
```

These are the two cases that I identified. Are there any other cases?

Note: Space characters inside string literals are not regarded as punctuator tokens (obviously).

***Update:*** As it turns out, a space character is **not** required in those cases. For example a keyword token and a identifier token have to be seperated by *something*, but that *something* does not have to be a space character. It could be any input element which is not a token (`WhiteSpace`, `LineTerminator` or `Comment`).

***Also...*** It seems that the space character is regarded as a `WhiteSpace` input element, and not a token at all, which would mean that **it's not a punctuator**.

Comment: For questions like this and your other excellent questions about the language, you'll find the regulars on the comp.lang.javascript newsgroup (http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/topics) are extremely knowledgeable. The Stack Overflow crowd is generally somewhat more practically minded.

Comment: @Tim I may consider resorting to the newsgroup, but only if I don't get a good answer here. But so far, I am very pleased with the answers.... Also, SO has a great page-rank. This question is the second-ranked result in a Google search for "javascript punctuators" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespaces are **not** required in any of these cases. You just have to write a syntax that is understandable for the parser. In other words: the machine has to know whether you're using a keyword like `function` or `new` or just defining another variable like `newFunction`.

Each keyword has to be delimited somehow - whitespaces are the most sensible and readable, however they can be replaced:

```
return/**/false;
return(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update** (2021): The spec is much clearer now, and space is definitely not in [the list of punctuators](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-punctuators). Space is whitespace, which is covered in the [White Space](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-white-space) section.

---

Answer from 2010:

I don't think that gap is meant to be a space, no, I think it's just a gap (an unfortunate one). If they really meant to be listing a space, I expect they'd use "*Whitespace*" as they have elsewhere in the document. But whitespace as a *punctuator* doesn't really make sense.

I believe spaces (and other forms of whitespace) are *delimiters*. The spec sort of defines them by omission rather than explicitly. The space is required between `function` and `x` because otherwise you have the token `functionx`, which is not of course a keyword (though it could be a name token — e.g., a variable, property, or function name).

You need delimiters around some tokens (*Identifiers* and *ReservedWords*), because that's how we recognize where those tokens begin and end — an *IdentifierName* starts with an *IdentifierStart* followed by zero or more *IdentifierParts*, a class which doesn't include whitespace or any of the characters used for punctuators. Other tokens (*Punctuators* for instance) we can recognize without delimiters. I think that's about it, and so your two rules are pretty much just two examples of the same rule: *IdentifierNames* must be delimited (by whitespace, by punctuators, by beginning or end of file, ...).

Somewhat off-topic, but of course not all delimiters are equal. Line-breaking delimiters are sometimes treated specially by the grammar for the horror that is "semicolon insertion".

Comment: @Crowder But, why is there a gap in the grid then? It must be intentionally. It is in the 3rd as well as the 5th edition, which came 10 years later. So they had enough time to format the spec appropriately.

Comment: It's hard to say whether or not that gap is supposed to be whitespace, but it's correct that whitespace characters are treated equally.  For instance, you can declare `else if` with a tab, or even a newline, separating the `else` and `if`.  Whitespace are delimiters, when you consider something like `1 .toFixed(2)`.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Having watched the specification document as it wound its way to a final copy (and interacted a bit with the guy overseeing it), I'm not at all surprised to find an editing ... *oddity* ... of that sort. Not even a little bit. Consider that the title of the PDF is "Final final final final draft Standard ECMA-262 5th Edition" and you get *some* sense of how tired they were of editing the thing. ;-)

Comment: @Šime Vidas: From 5.1.2 of 5th edition: " *Input elements other than white space* and comments *form the terminal symbols* for the syntactic grammar for ECMAScript *and are called ECMAScript tokens*. *These tokens are* the reserved words, identifiers, literals, and *punctuators* of the ECMAScript language." This would seem to be the explicit elimination of the possibility of that gap intending to include a space as a punctuator.

Comment: @patrick: I figured it out even as you were doing that, sorry. :-)

Comment: @Crowder The gap sticks out to much. I find it hard to believe that in the last 10 years no one in the technical comity noticed / cared.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: This is just a guess, but maybe they retained the gap in order to make it easier to compare the new spec to the older. By retaining the gap, it becomes more obvious that nothing has changed. Again, just a guess.

Comment: I'd hazard my own guess that parts of the spec that don't change *aren't* changed and that's why the gap is still there.

Comment: I looked at the 2nd edition and the gap is not present. So, the gap was **introduced** in the 3rd edition. LOL what a mess.

Comment: is '\n' a punctuator? If it's not being skipped

Comment: @DickWilliams - `\n` is a [line terminator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-line-terminators), not a punctuator.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but I would say that spaces aren't actually required anywhere. They are used just as one of many alternatives to generate word boundaries between keywords. This means you could just as well replace them with other characters.

If what you want is to remove the unnecessary spaces from some code I would say that spaces (white-space to be more exact, tabs will work just as well) are mandatory only where there are no other means of separating keywords and/or variable identifiers. I.e. where by removing the white-space you no longer have the same keywords and identifiers in the resulting code.

---

What follows is not exactly relevant to your needs but you may find it interesting. You can write you examples so that they no longer have those spaces. I hope none of the examples are wrong.

`x=function(){}` instead of `function x(){}`
`this.x=null;` instead of `var x;`
`return(x);` instead of `return x;`
`typeof(x);` instead of `typeof x;`
<del>`y=X();` instead of `y = new X();`</del>
`return(false)` instead of `return false`
`if(x){}else{if(y){}else{}}` instead of `if(x){}else if(y){}else{}`

Comment: Mmmmm... interesting. But braces won't work for `function`, `var` and `new`,  will they?

Comment: Nope. I don't think you can enclose in any of those cases. But, as Crozin did in his answer, you can add multi-line comment blocks pretty much anywhere. For function you can trick it by using `fn=function`, but nothing comes to mind for other cases.

Comment: For new you can just not write it, I think. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: And instead of `var x;` you probably can do `this.x=null;` anywhere. But this isn't what Šime wanted to know :)

Comment: @Alin Yes, space characters are not required anywhere. However, they are the *de facto* standard when it comes to seperating two keywords or a keyword and an identifier.

Comment: Well, yes, because the space is since ancient times the standard way of separating *things*. Also the space bar is very big and conveniently placed.

Comment: `y=X()` is definitely different from `y=new X()`